# SQL Server time interval to multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have this record with StartDateTime and EndDateTime and I want the result to be in rows with 15 minutes interval:

Sample data:

`FName | StartDateTime  | EndDateTime
:----- | -----------:   | :--------------:
Juan   | 08/01/2017 1:00| 08/01/2017 8:00`

Result:

`FName | Interval
:----- | -----------:
Juan   | 08/01/2017 1:00
Juan   | 08/01/2017 1:15
Juan   | 08/01/2017 1:30
Juan   | 08/01/2017 1:45
Juan   | 08/01/2017 2:00`

Until it reaches to its EndDateTime, how can I achieve this in SQL. I'm thinking using looping statement or cte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to a TVF (Table-Valued Function)

I'll often use this udf to create dynamic date/time ranges.  It is faster than a recursive CTE and parameter driven.

The parameters are Date1, Date2, DatePart, and Increment

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([FName] varchar(50),[StartDateTime] datetime,[EndDateTime] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Juan','08/01/2017 1:00','08/01/2017 8:00')

Select A.FName
      ,B.* 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](A.StartDateTime,A.EndDateTime,'MI',15) B
```

**Returns**

```
FName   RetSeq  RetVal
Juan    1       2017-08-01 01:00:00.000
Juan    2       2017-08-01 01:15:00.000
Juan    3       2017-08-01 01:30:00.000
Juan    4       2017-08-01 01:45:00.000
Juan    5       2017-08-01 02:00:00.000
...
Juan    29      2017-08-01 08:00:00.000
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `recursive query` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    FName varchar(20),
    StartDatetime datetime,
    EndDatetime datetime
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    FName,
    StartDatetime,
    EndDatetime
)
VALUES
('Juan', '2017-08-01 1:00', '2017-08-01 8:00')

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.FName, sd.StartDatetime AS Interval, sd.EndDatetime
    FROM @SampleData sd

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.FName, dateadd(minute, 15, t.Interval)  AS Interval, t.EndDatetime
    FROM temp t
    WHERE dateadd(minute, 15, t.Interval) <= t.EndDatetime
)
SELECT t.FName,
      t.Interval  
 FROM temp t
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/CELP88345

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use date table but you can generate as below:

```
Select Fname, RowN as Interval from #dates
cross apply (
    Select top(datediff(hh,startdatetime, enddatetime)*4+1) RowN =dateadd(mi,  (row_number() over(order by (Select NULL)) -1)*15 ,startdatetime)
        from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2 ) a
```

Output as below:

```
+-------+-------------------------+
| Fname |        Interval         |
+-------+-------------------------+
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 01:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 01:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 01:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 01:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 02:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 02:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 02:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 02:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 03:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 03:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 03:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 03:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 04:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 04:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 04:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 04:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 05:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 05:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 05:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 05:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 06:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 06:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 06:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 06:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 07:00:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 07:15:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 07:30:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 07:45:00.000 |
| Juan  | 2017-08-01 08:00:00.000 |
+-------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursive CTE to achieve the expected results.

Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/821a5/11

```
with cte as 
(
   select Fname,StartDateTime
   from Table1
   union all
   select  Fname,DATEADD(mi,15,StartDateTime) as StartDateTime
   from cte
   where  DATEADD(mi,15,StartDateTime) <= '2017-01-08 08:00:00:000'
  )

 select Fname, StartDateTime  from cte;
```